# How to Show All Search Verticals?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, navigation, display-template

We are woking on a search center that needs 6 search verticals (everything, doc, news, events, people, pages.) If it's just 5 verticals, everything align horizontally fine. However, if it's 6 verticals, SharePoint automatically creates "..." in the end and make the last one as dropdown.

[image]

How can I change that and show all verticals together at same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I would just answer my own question.

Edit webpart > Change the maximum links

[image]

Comment: Yep, this setting has to be made on every Search Navigation web part on every page.